# OnTouchListener - ActionMove (android) is giving different positions at one touch point

Tags: android, events, view, move

I'm trying to make moveable text in my FrameLayout. In TextView I've set OnTouchListener which you can see below. The problem is, that when I'm touching textview (without finger move), OnTouchListener is giving different positions, and my TextView is jumping between different positions.. I've put also LogCat result, which is connected with that situation. Thank you for any help.

```
onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.w("KKK", "ONTOUCH EVENT: "+motionEvent.getAction());
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    lastTouchX = motionEvent.getX();
                    lastTouchY = motionEvent.getY();
                    Log.w("KKK", "ACTION DOWN X: " + lastTouchX + " Y: " + lastTouchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.w("KKK", "ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: " + lastTouchX + " Y: " + lastTouchY);
                    float beforeX = lastTouchX, beforeY = lastTouchY;
                    lastTouchX = motionEvent.getX();
                    lastTouchY = motionEvent.getY();
                    Log.w("KKK", "ACTION MOVE AFTER X: " + lastTouchX + " Y: " + lastTouchY);
                    Log.w("KKK", "ACTION MOVE DELTA X: " + (beforeX - lastTouchX) + " Y: " + (beforeY - lastTouchY));
                    float delX = lastTouchX - beforeX;
                    float delY = lastTouchY - beforeY;
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp1 =  (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    lp1.setMargins(lp1.leftMargin+(int)delX, lp1.topMargin+(int)delY, lp1.rightMargin, lp1.bottomMargin);
                    view.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        };
    };
```

logcat:

```
07-23 14:02:49.494: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 0
07-23 14:02:49.494: W/KKK(24257): ACTION DOWN X: 80.0 Y: 70.0
07-23 14:02:49.514: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.514: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 80.0 Y: 70.0
07-23 14:02:49.514: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 185.4158 Y: 73.4769
07-23 14:02:49.514: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -105.4158 Y: -3.4768982
07-23 14:02:49.554: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.554: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 185.4158 Y: 73.4769
07-23 14:02:49.554: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 71.92239 Y: 68.4794
07-23 14:02:49.554: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 113.49341 Y: 4.9974976
07-23 14:02:49.574: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.574: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 71.92239 Y: 68.4794
07-23 14:02:49.574: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 185.43243 Y: 72.4794
07-23 14:02:49.574: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -113.51004 Y: -4.0
07-23 14:02:49.604: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.604: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 185.43243 Y: 72.4794
07-23 14:02:49.604: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 68.70996 Y: 68.4794
07-23 14:02:49.604: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 116.72247 Y: 4.0
07-23 14:02:49.644: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.644: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 68.70996 Y: 68.4794
07-23 14:02:49.644: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 183.23611 Y: 71.7446
07-23 14:02:49.644: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -114.52615 Y: -3.2651978
07-23 14:02:49.654: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.654: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 183.23611 Y: 71.7446
07-23 14:02:49.654: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 67.1391 Y: 68.04501
07-23 14:02:49.654: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 116.097015 Y: 3.699585
07-23 14:02:49.694: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.694: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 67.1391 Y: 68.04501
07-23 14:02:49.694: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 184.44492 Y: 71.48065
07-23 14:02:49.694: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -117.30582 Y: -3.4356384
07-23 14:02:49.714: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.714: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 184.44492 Y: 71.48065
07-23 14:02:49.714: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 67.444916 Y: 68.48065
07-23 14:02:49.714: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 117.0 Y: 3.0
07-23 14:02:49.724: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.724: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 67.444916 Y: 68.48065
07-23 14:02:49.724: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 184.44492 Y: 71.48065
07-23 14:02:49.724: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -117.0 Y: -3.0
07-23 14:02:49.764: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.764: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 184.44492 Y: 71.48065
07-23 14:02:49.764: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 67.444916 Y: 68.48065
07-23 14:02:49.764: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 117.0 Y: 3.0
07-23 14:02:49.794: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.794: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 67.444916 Y: 68.48065
07-23 14:02:49.794: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 179.32318 Y: 70.19916
07-23 14:02:49.794: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -111.878265 Y: -1.7185059
07-23 14:02:49.814: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.814: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 179.32318 Y: 70.19916
07-23 14:02:49.814: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 69.45322 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.814: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 109.869965 Y: 0.71725464
07-23 14:02:49.854: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.854: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 69.45322 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.854: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 173.34717 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.854: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -103.89395 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:49.864: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.864: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 173.34717 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.864: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.864: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 101.88562 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:49.904: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.904: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.904: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.904: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -101.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:49.934: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.934: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.934: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.934: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 101.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:49.975: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:49.975: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.975: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:49.975: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -101.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.015: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.015: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:50.015: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:50.015: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 101.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.025: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.025: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 71.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:50.035: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:50.035: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -101.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.065: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.065: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 172.46155 Y: 69.4819
07-23 14:02:50.065: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 69.128845 Y: 68.703705
07-23 14:02:50.065: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 103.3327 Y: 0.77819824
07-23 14:02:50.075: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.075: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 69.128845 Y: 68.703705
07-23 14:02:50.085: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 170.1532 Y: 68.04462
07-23 14:02:50.085: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -101.02435 Y: 0.65908813
07-23 14:02:50.115: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.115: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 170.1532 Y: 68.04462
07-23 14:02:50.115: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.115: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.685425 Y: -0.4385376
07-23 14:02:50.135: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.135: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.135: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.135: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.165: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.165: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.165: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.165: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.185: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.185: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.185: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.185: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.225: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.225: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.225: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.225: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.235: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.235: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.235: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.235: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.285: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.285: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.295: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.295: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.305: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.305: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.305: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.305: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.345: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.345: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.345: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.345: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.365: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.365: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.365: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.365: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.375: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.375: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.375: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.375: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: 99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.395: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 2
07-23 14:02:50.395: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE BEFORE X: 70.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.395: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE AFTER X: 169.46777 Y: 68.483154
07-23 14:02:50.395: W/KKK(24257): ACTION MOVE DELTA X: -99.0 Y: 0.0
07-23 14:02:50.395: W/KKK(24257): ONTOUCH EVENT: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I've changed

```
motionEvent.getX();
```

to

```
motionEvent.getRawX();
```

Similar with Y-coordinates methods,

and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

All coordinates are relative to the view.
If you are setting onTouchListener on your TextView then you are in for trouble.
Since your TextView is under your finger every move of TextView will produce different value for the same touch location on the screen. That's why your slight finger movements will mess up the whole system.

Raw coordinates are absolute, so it's a way out, but it will be harder to coordinate with parent layout (to hit bounds on move and stuff)

You should set your onTouchListener in your FrameLayout which is absolute also (since it doesn't move and one concrete point on the screen will always produce the same values), and modify the onTouchListener to check if TexView was hit on touch and if yes - do some dragging